# Including flask-marshmallow causes failure

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I've got flask-marshmallow of 0.13.0 version

I'm able to access SQLAlchemyAutoSchema in the flask app

when i try to run the application, i get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'SQLAlchemyAutoSchema'
```

initialisation of flask marshmallow

```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
        
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    ma = Marshmallow()
```

I've registered both db and ma with flask app
code:

```
from apis import ma

from apis.models import User


class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: Is `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` installed? See https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/blob/dev/src/flask_marshmallow/__init__.py#L25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask-marshmallow` [has a dependency on `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/blob/dev/src/flask_marshmallow/__init__.py#L25) for the `SQLAlchemySchema` classes to be defined.

Make sure you also install `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`.